# My ListView is displaying duplicates

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, listview

I am trying to allow a user of a buy and sell website to only be able to edit the products that they have put up for sale.  I have got that, but the result is now that it shows duplicates.  I am new to Stack Overflow and asp.net so apologies if I am not following the correct procedures.

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="itemsjoin" runat="server"  ConnectionString = '<%$ConnectionStrings:itemsconnection%>' SelectCommand="SELECT itemsupdate.ID, itemsupdate.itemname, itemsupdate.price, itemsupdate.image, itemsupdate.description, itemsupdate.location, itemsupdate.productID, itemsupdate.userID, producttype.productname
             FROM producttype, users, itemsupdate                 
             WHERE ([userID] = @userID)">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="userID" QueryStringField="userID" Type="Int32"/>
     </SelectParameters>
         </asp:SqlDataSource>

         <asp:ListView ID="itemsdisplay" runat="server"  DataSourceID = "itemsjoin" DataKeyNames="ID">

             <ItemTemplate>

                 <div class="col-md-4"> 
                     <div class="itemtext">
                 </br>
                 <asp:Label ID="itemname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("itemname") %>'></asp:Label></br>

                 <asp:Label ID="itemprice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("price") %>'></asp:Label>

                 <asp:HyperLink ID="itemhyperlink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#"itemediting.aspx?itemid="+Eval("ID")%>'>

                    <div class="imgright">
                         <asp:Image ID="imagepic" runat="server" ImageURL='<%# "../../files/"+Eval("image") %>' width="200px" /></asp:HyperLink>
                     </div>

                     </div>

                 </div>
             </ItemTemplate>



         </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: In order to get (better) answers, I would recommend you to strip down your code to the sql part, the rest is useless. As to give you some hints to your question, try to improve your sql. You are doing a join there which will automatically lead to multiple rows having same product listed (for each user, for each item update). You should check also this link: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: @Learner thanks. I wasn't sure where the problem was in the code, hence why I have quite a lot there.

Comment: I hope you realized that I wanted to help you by not giving you the solution right away (it was anyway very simple)...The time you would spend on asking such questions, would be the same as doing a small research and learning by yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add DISTINCT in your query

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  itemsupdate.ID, itemsupdate.itemname, itemsupdate.price, itemsupdate.image, itemsupdate.description, itemsupdate.location, itemsupdate.productID, itemsupdate.userID, producttype.productname
             FROM producttype, users, itemsupdate                 
             WHERE ([userID] = @userID)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm @sajeetharan. I've a lot to learn! Much appreciated.